# Que erro é esse "D/TAG: Retorno...: [Lcom.example.gustavo.domanda.ConsultarPojo;@11c78941"

Tags: android

Tenho o seguinte código que deve retornar uma lista de dados

```
package com.example.gustavo.domanda;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConsultarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lvReservas;

private int idusuario;
private String nome;
private String sobrenome;
private RequestQueue mVolleyRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_consultar);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extra != null){
        idusuario = extra.getInt("idusuario");
        nome = extra.getString("nome");
        sobrenome = extra.getString("sobrenome");
    }

    getAgenda(idusuario);

}

private void getAgenda(int idusuario) {
    int opcao = 3; //mostrar agenda do cliente
    final ArrayList<ConsultarPojo> agendaCliente = new ArrayList<>();
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    GsonRequest<ConsultarPojo[]> request = new GsonRequest<>("http://reservacomdomanda.com/areaAdmin/api/admin_estabelecimento/reqScheduleProJson.php?" +
            "idcliente="+idusuario+"&opcao="+opcao, ConsultarPojo[].class, null, new Response.Listener<ConsultarPojo[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ConsultarPojo[] response) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Retorno... " + response);
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                ConsultarPojo agc = new ConsultarPojo();
                agc.dia = response[i].dia;
                agc.hora = response[i].hora;
                agendaCliente.add(agc);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<ConsultarPojo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ConsultarPojo>(ConsultarActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, agendaCliente);
            lvReservas = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvReservas));
            lvReservas.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error.Response", String.valueOf(error));
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}

}
```

E na linha onde eu escrevi "TAG", "Retorno... " + response, no console aparece

> D/TAG: Retorno... [Lcom.example.gustavo.domanda.ConsultarPojo;@f6cde00

Que erro ou problema é esse?

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é erro, é a string que representa o objecto.

Quando usa um objecto dessa forma, conversão implícita para string, é usado o retorno do método `toString()` desse objecto.

A implementação padrão do método [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) retorna uma string consistindo no nome da classe, da qual o objecto é uma instância, o caractere `@` e a representação hexadecimal do código hash do objecto, o equivalente a

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

Comment: E o que devo fazer pra aparecer os dados do objeto? Já coloquei response.toString() mas não adiantou

Comment: @GustavoSevero, você fez uma pergunta e ela foi respondida. Se não era isso que queria perguntar, faça outra pergunta.

Comment: `"TAG", "Retorno... " + response` é igual a `"TAG", "Retorno... " + response.toString()`

Comment: Colocar response.toString() não ajudou, infelizmente

Comment: Eu não disse para você pôr `response.toString()`. Pelo contrário, disse que era o mesmo. Você perguntou, em relação ao que aparecia no log, "Que erro ou problema é esse?", foi a isso que eu respondi.

Comment: Beleza, valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando concatenar no log uma string ("Retorno...") direto com um Array de objetos (response). Não é erro, ele apenas pegou o "header" que descreve o Array. Se quiser pegar um item específico do Array, use os indexadores, e como é Array de objetos de uma classe sua, tem que chamar o getter ou a variável que você quer exibir do objeto.

Ex: Pelo seu código, vi que sua classe `ConsultarPojo` tem uma variável `dia`, então ficaria algo assim:

```
Log.d("TAG", "Retorno... " + response[0].dia);
```

Comment: Desculpe, de que "header" você fala?
E na verdade quero buscar todos os dados do array... Quero ver o que está vindo

Comment: Tem dia e hora... Ambos devem aparecer kkkk

Comment: Estou falando de um header interno que o código gera depois de compilado. Afinal o Array não é uma String. Concatenações só funcionam entre Strings. Se quiser pegar todos os valores do Array, faça um loop que concatene todos os dados do mesmo

Comment: Eu só dei um exemplo de algo "concatenável" no seu código. Use as variáveis da classe e membros do Array que quiser apartir daí.

Comment: Mas já tem um FOR pra pegar os dados que eu quero